# AJAX CORS equivalent to this JSONP AJAX request - allowing to read cookies and allow any domain access

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cors, jsonp

How can I do this JSONP AJAX request the CORS way?

This JSONP AJAX request allows any domain to access a domain and can read the cookies for that domain. What is the exact equivalent for doing it the AJAX CORS way?

JSONP AJAX working example:

```
// Domain 1 (any domain can do this request to domain 2 and attempt to read cookies)

    // JS
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://domain2.com/example',
        type: "post",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });


// Domain 2

    // PHP

    // Read a cookie for this domain
    $testCookie = $_COOKIE[0];

    $callback = $_POST['callback'];
    echo $callback . '(' . json_encode($testCookie) . ')';
    die();
```

AJAX with CORS equivalent:

```
// Domain 1 (I want any domain to be able to do this request to domain 2 and attempt to read cookies)

    // JS
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });


    // Domain 2

    // PHP

    // Read a cookie for this domain
    $testCookie = $_COOKIE[0];

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 604800');
    header("Content-type: application/json");

    echo json_encode($testCookie);
    die();
```

This has an error message saying you can't have `*` wildcards when using `withCredentials: true`, but the `withCredentials: true` is needed to read cookies. I can change `*` in `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` to the URL of domain 1, which will work, but how can I get this work so any domain has access like in my jSONP example? From my research, this can't be done, but would this be allowed to work perfectly fine for JSONP AJAX request?

Comment: Set it to the value of the Origin request header.

Comment: Dont use `*` if you want `*`, just copy the `origin` $_SERVER header into that header.

Comment: More robust php cors set up that will do what you ask https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/1175966

Comment: Dont feel bad, most people do it wrong https://github.com/search?q=Access-Control-Allow-Origin%3A+%2A&type=Code